# Google Charts: Timeline move rowLabel text in another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

What is the correct svg element in the chart for the timeline rowLabel?

I'm trying to place the rowlabel (row names) in a div to the left of the chart and remove the actual row label. 
I can remove the rowlabel easy with:

```
timeline: { groupByRowLabel: true, showrowLabels: false}
```

But I can't find a way to move the actual labels to the left in a separate div so that a huge horizontal scroll will keep the row labels frozen to the left.

```
function afterDraw() {

//trying to move the rowlabelhere

 var header = document.getElementById('rowlabel');
header.innerHTML = '';
 var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
 var g = svg.getElementsByTagName('g')[0];
 var gtext = g.getElementsByTagName('text')[0];
 var svgNew = header.appendChild(svg.cloneNode());
 var gNew = svgNew.appendChild(gtext.cloneNode(true));
 var height = parseFloat(gNew.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].getAttribute('y')) - 25;
 gNew.setAttribute('transform','translate(60,-'+height+')');
 }
```

Here's a codepen with the issue:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZmKpo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove the labels as you've described,
then use the [group()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) method to pull the labels from the data table,
and add them to a container to the left of the chart.

in order to get the labels in the correct order,
we can group on both label and begin date,
then sort by begin date.

```
var group = google.visualization.data.group(
  data,
  [0, 1],
  [{
    column: 0,
    type: 'number',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
  }]
);
group.sort([{column: 1}]);
```

but this will cause some of the labels to repeat,
so we can use an array to filter those out,
as we add them to the container.

```
var rowLabels = [];
var rowElements = [];
var labels = document.getElementById('labels');
for (var i = 0; i < group.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  var team = group.getValue(i, 0);
  if (rowLabels.indexOf(team) === -1) {
    rowLabels.push(team);
    var label = labels.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    label.className = 'label';
    label.innerHTML = team;
    rowElements.push(label);
  }
}
```

then on the `'ready'` event, we can adjust the label height,
to match the chart rows.

```
var rows = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
var rowIndex = -1;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(rows, function(rect) {
  if (rect.getAttribute('x') === '0') {
    rowIndex++;
    if (rowIndex < rowElements.length) {
      var rowHeight = (parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('height')) - 1) + 'px';
      rowElements[rowIndex].style.height = rowHeight;
      rowElements[rowIndex].style.lineHeight = rowHeight;
    }
  }
});
```

see following working snippet...
(view the snippet in *Full page* mode to see the full effect)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
      {id: 'team', label: 'Team', type: 'string'},
      {id: 'start', label: 'Season Start Date', type: 'date'},
      {id: 'end', label: 'Season End Date', type: 'date'}
    ],
    rows: [
      {c: [{v: 'Baltimore Ravens'},     {v: 'Date(2000, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2005, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers'},  {v: 'Date(2005, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2006, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Indianapolis Colts'},   {v: 'Date(2006, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2007, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New York Giants'},      {v: 'Date(2007, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2008, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers'},  {v: 'Date(2008, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2009, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New Orleans Saints'},   {v: 'Date(2009, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2010, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Green Bay Packers'},    {v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Green Bay Packers'},    {v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2005, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers'},  {v: 'Date(2005, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2006, 1, 5)'}]},
    ]
  });

  var group = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [0, 1],
    [{
      column: 0,
      type: 'number',
      label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
    }]
  );
  group.sort([{column: 1}]);

  var rowLabels = [];
  var rowElements = [];
  var labels = document.getElementById('labels');
  for (var i = 0; i < group.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var team = group.getValue(i, 0);
    if (rowLabels.indexOf(team) === -1) {
      rowLabels.push(team);
      var label = labels.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      label.className = 'label';
      label.innerHTML = team;
      rowElements.push(label);
    }
  }

  var options = {
    height: 650,
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: true,
      showRowLabels: false
    },
    width: 1000
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', afterDraw);
  chart.draw(data, options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });

  function afterDraw() {
    var header = document.getElementById('header');
    header.innerHTML = '';
    var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    var g = svg.getElementsByTagName('g')[1];
    var svgNew = header.appendChild(svg.cloneNode());
    var gNew = svgNew.appendChild(g.cloneNode(true));
    var height = parseFloat(gNew.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].getAttribute('y')) - 25;
    gNew.setAttribute('transform','translate(0,-'+height+')');
    g.parentNode.removeChild(g);

    var rows = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    var rowIndex = -1;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(rows, function(rect) {
      if (rect.getAttribute('x') === '0') {
        rowIndex++;
        if (rowIndex < rowElements.length) {
          var rowHeight = (parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('height')) - 1) + 'px';
          rowElements[rowIndex].style.height = rowHeight;
          rowElements[rowIndex].style.lineHeight = rowHeight;
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
  height: 56px;
}

#labels {
  border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  margin-top: 56px;
}

.label {
  border-top: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.label:first-child {
  border: none;
}

.label:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.label:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.scroll {
  width: 800px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="nowrap">
  <div class="inline" id="labels"></div>
  <div class="inline scroll">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saving the day again. Thank you, sir. No wonder I was not able to just move the svg that contains the names to the right. It's because it's not one element and I can't use the same method that we used for the date headings, correct?

Comment: that's right, we could move each label individually, but then we would be left with an empty space, I think removing the original labels first works best.

Comment: Additionally, is there a quick way to "pin" the two divs so that they both scroll horizontally in unison? If I scroll down on the div with names, it scrolls down correctly, if I scroll down on the timeline it hesitates for a few pixels before it catches on.

Comment: try adding this to the `.scroll` css class --> `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: Thanks, that works but I think I actually need the "y" to scroll here. In both cases, the header div is now not frozen which makes the dates disappear from view when scrolling down.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have been trying this for a few days now. I can't understand how to make that top div (header) stay fixed when scrolling vertically while maintaining horizontal scroll.